# ReactJS Multiple lines of input using Form

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am implementing an input form and I am hoping that it could have a fix line limit. For example, for one box, it would be a 3-line input box. If more than 3 lines, there will be ideally a scroll bar on y-axis (i.e., no overflow in x axis). My current code is

```
<Form>
  <FormGroup>
    <ControlLabel>
      Label
    </ControlLabel>
    <InputGroup>
      <FormControl value='default' onChange={<some function>} />
    </InputGroup>

  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

but it only rendered one line's input.

Edited: using `textarea`, the font seems to be very tiny.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following snippet fixes the described issue:

```
<Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
  <Form.Label>Example textarea</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control as="textarea" rows="3" />
</Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 1):

The componentClass prop of a FormControl is "input" by default, which renders a text input.

A text input is single line.

So try setting the componentClass prop of FormControl to "textarea":

```
<Form>
    <FormGroup>
        <ControlLabel>
            Label
        </ControlLabel>
        <InputGroup>
            <FormControl componentClass="textarea" value='default' onChange={<some function>} />
        </InputGroup>
    </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I could limit the height of the text box (e.g., # of lines)?

Comment: Also, it seems like the text is very tiny. I edited my question with a snapshot. Could you take a look?

Comment: In html, textarea's number of rows is defined by the row prop: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Textarea
FormControl should accept this prop, look into React-bootstrap's documentation or do not use react-bootstrap. The font size is determined by css as in any other text element, adjust your css or look into reat-bootstrap documentation. You also may be able to set it with a style prop: `style={{ fontSize: '14px' }}`